# Custom TransferHandler for pasting text excludes cutting and copying

Tags: java, copying, pasting

I'm trying to make a custom TransferHandler that will strip some text when I paste into a JEditorPane. But when I set my JEditorPane with my TransferHandler, copying and cutting no longer function. Is there a way to get it back? All I really want to customize is the pasting function.

Here is how I set up my JEditorPane:

```
JEditorPane jep= new JEditorPane();

myTransferHandler th = new myTransferHandler();
jep.setTransferHandler(th);
```

This is my TransferHandler class:

```
public class myTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        JEditorPane jep = (JEditorPane) support.getComponent();
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) jep.getDocument();
        int offset = jep.getCaretPosition();
        try {
            Object data = support.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor(String.class, "String"));
            if(jep.getSelectedText() != null)
                //remove any highlighted text
                jep.getDocument().remove(jep.getSelectionStart(), jep.getSelectionEnd() - jep.getSelectionStart());
            doc.insertString(offset, (String) data, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Insert String failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }               
}
```

I read in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html) (in the "Note" section) that if I install my own TransferHandler, it won't allow me to do other types of transfers (like cutting and copying)?? Does that mean if I use a custom TransferHandler, I'd have to implement the entire class???

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. I only wanted to paste plain text into my JEditorPane. When you set the Content Type of the JEditorPane to "text/html" to display html code, copying from a website and pasting to the JEditorPane will add on extra html content that I didnt want (like Rich Text formatted stuff). That is why I was searching for a way to just paste plain text.

I used this [TextTransferHandler](http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/TextCutPasteProject/src/dnd/TextTransferHandler.java) to do so.

Comment: http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/TextCutPasteProject/src/dnd/TextTransferHandler.java   ???

Answer (score 0):

the JEditorPane uses a subclass from transferhandler, a so called TextTransferHandler; you should subclass that TextTransferHandler, but unfortunately it's a private class.

you can copy the source code from javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.TextTransferHandler and make your own (copyOf)  TextTransferHandler.

That textTransferHandler should do all you want...

http://j6a.ru/_basic_text_u_i_8java_source.html

line 2175

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your response. Your suggestion to look at the TextTransferHandler class helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello Ted, i'm glad i could help a little although i'm a little embarrassed that i couldn't provide more help ^^   good luck with your project!